# Customized Table of Contents APA style

Tags: table-of-contents, apa-style

I am trying to produce the Table of Contents same as shown in Picture separately. Is there any template for this? I just have "Table of Contents" but no document attached with it.[image]

My problems for this Stack exchange template are:

1. Instead of "Contents" on the top I want "TABLE OF CONTENTS"
2. I do not want "Acknowledgement" and "List of Table" listed as section but want as shown in picture attached.
3. I want to manually control the page listing as in my code you can see all of page numbers are 2 but I want them as attached in picture.

minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection)}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph)}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph)}{1em}{}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{1em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{2em}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{2.5em}
\setlength{\cftparanumwidth}{3.8em}
\setlength{\cftsubparanumwidth}{3.8em}

\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{1.8em}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{4.1em}
\setlength{\cftparaindent}{5.9em}
\setlength{\cftsubparaindent}{7.7em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\section{LIST OF TABLES}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Background}
\subsection{Evolution of Missing Data Estimation Method}
\subsection{Missing Data Mechanism}
\subsubsection{Missing Completely at Random}
\subsubsection{Missing at Random}
\subsubsection{Missing not at Random}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what `documentclass` do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `\section*` and `\addcontentsline`. See the code below.
2. See the code below.
3. Simply set the `page` counter to the desired value (see the code below, where a `\MyNum` command allows you to specify the desired page number).
4. In a comment it was requested to have 1 inch margins in the page. This can be achieved using

   ```
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
   ```

I suppressed the parts of the original code that were not esential to the question/solution. The easiest way to get the desired result is to use the `\cftsetindents` command for the sectional units

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\renewcommand\contentsname{\MakeUppercase{Table of Contents}}

\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftaftertoctitle{\hfill\null\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftbeforesecskip{2pt}
\renewcommand\cftbeforesubsecskip{2pt}
\renewcommand\cftbeforesubsubsecskip{2pt}

\cftsetindents{section}{0pt}{1em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{1em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{2.5em}{2.5em}

\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont}

\newcommand\MyNum[1]{%
  \newpage
  \setcounter{page}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\MyNum{5}
\section*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\MyNum{8}
\section*{LIST OF TABLES}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF TABLES}
\MyNum{9}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Background}
\MyNum{10}
\subsection{Evolution of Missing Data Estimation Method}
\MyNum{12}
\subsection{Missing Data Mechanism}
\subsubsection{Missing Completely at Random}
\MyNum{14}
\subsubsection{Missing at Random}
\MyNum{15}
\subsubsection{Missing not at Random}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Remark:

If `babel` is loaded, the line

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{\MakeUppercase{Table of Contents}}
```

will have no effect. In this case, the redefinition will have to be done using

```
\addto\captions<language>{\renewcommand\contentsname{\MakeUppercase{Table of Contents}}}
```

as described elsewhere in some other answers in this site.

Comment: Excellent Job .. You solved all my problems except for problem (2) where I do not want "Acknowledgement" and "List of Table" listed as section but want as shown in picture attached...

Comment: @user35571 Ah, yes. Sorry. I've fixed it in my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome!! One More thing ...can we have 1" margins on all sides of this page ? This is the last thing I wont bother you anymore

Comment: @user35571 Sure. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, using the `titletoc`, `titlesec` and `etoolbox` packages. The latter allows to automatically add unnumbered sections to the table of contents if the value of a boolean is "true", incorporating the `\addcontentsline…` command into the. `\titleformat{\section}` command. I also added a dot after the section numbers, as in the OP's example.

```
        \documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}
        \usepackage[pagestyles, explicit]{titlesec}%
        \usepackage[leftlabels]{titletoc}%

        \usepackage{etoolbox}
        \newbool{addtoc}%initial value:  false

        \titleformat{\section}[display]%
        {\bfseries\Large\filcenter}
        {\LARGE\thesection}
        {0.5pc}
        {\vspace{0.5pc}\Huge\MakeUppercase{#1}}%

        \titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[display]
        {\bfseries\large\filcenter}
        {}
        {0.5pc}
        {\vspace{0.5pc}\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
        [\ifbool{addtoc}{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}{}]%

          \titlecontents{section}[2em]{\smallskip}%\vspace{1cm}
          {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{1em}}%numbered
          {\hspace*{-1em}}%numberless
          {\dotfill\contentspage}[\medskip]%
        %
         \titlecontents{subsection}[4em]{\smallskip}%
          {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2em}}%numbered
          {\hspace*{-1em}}%{-1em}}%numberless
          {\dotfill\contentspage}[\smallskip]%\vspace{-0,25ex}
        %
         \titlecontents{subsubsection}[6.75em]{}%
          {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2.75em}}%numbered
          {\hspace*{-1em}}%numberless
          {\dotfill\contentspage}[\smallskip]

        \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Title of contents}

        \begin{document}

        \tableofcontents

        \booltrue{addtoc}
         \newpage
        \section*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}

        Blahblahblah
        \newpage

        \section{INTRODUCTION}

        \subsection{Background}

        \subsection{Evolution of Missing Data Evolution Method Evolution of Missing Data Evolution Method}

        \subsection*{Missing Data Mechanisms}

        \subsubsection{Missing Completely at Random Missing Completely at Random Missing Completely}
        \subsubsection{Missing at Random}

        \subsection{Missing Not at Random}

        \subsection{Strategies for Missing Data}
        \newpage

        \section{LITERATURE REVIEW}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user35571: I've added another solution using `titlesec/titletoc` that automates the inclusion of unnumbered sections in the table of contents.